# i can't import pygame in visual studio code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, pygame

I installed Pygame Snippets in my Visual Studio Code and then i wrote `import pygame`, i always got an error

```
import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

I looked for any ways how to fix it at the web, but nothing helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pygame Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tushortz.pygame-snippets) is just an extension on vscode. It does not install [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/) for you. Follow the [getting started page for Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted) to install.

Answer (score 1):

You should installl pygame package from pip, not snippets.

Snippets is a vscode feature that help you fast coding with code templates.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue in vs code, basically I had 2 python installed one from microsoft store and another one from vs code software. To solve this I just uninstalled the one from microsoft store and installed pygame by
`pip install pygame`
now I am able to access the module.

Answer (score 0):

install pygame module through powershell:
Use the command `pip install pygame`

Answer (score 0):

To actually install `pygame` you need to do it from command line/terminal. The command to install is `pip install pygame`

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the dropdown button on the right of the run Button, you can click on: 'Run Python File' or 'Debug Python File'. That worked out for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).