# Pygame module not found

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame

I have installed pygame in the terminal but I cannot find it in vscode and get an error.

Edit:

I found that I was using the wrong python interpreter see my later answer

Comment: Do you have multiple Python installations?

Comment: How do I check that @Rabbid76? I know I have (and use) python 3.9 but I don't know if I have another installation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module not found error in VS code despite the fact that I installed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56658553/module-not-found-error-in-vs-code-despite-the-fact-that-i-installed-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Original answer* - by [@MOStudios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17431241/mostudios) (me)

## Two possible solutions

### Check the python interpreter being used

When any `.py` file is open in the editor and is currently being used, near the bottom left, it says `Python <version> <32/64>-bit`. Tap it and select the directory that contains the python interpreter version that has kivy installed.

Check the following image for any help

[image: Click on the highlighted area in the bottom left]

The platform I was using was a chromebook, but the location of changing the editor is the same

### Manually install within VScode

Run `pip install kivy` to ensure that vscode uses it

Answer (score 0):

Try

Pip install pygame

on the vscode terminal.

If that doesn’t work check this out:

[i can't import pygame in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59224850/i-cant-import-pygame-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Neither of those worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Main reason I see is your project is not configured correctly.
probably not the right interpreter or virtual environment.
have a look on your settings and see that anything looks as it should be(right python version).

have a look:
[Module not found error in VS code despite the fact that I installed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56658553/module-not-found-error-in-vs-code-despite-the-fact-that-i-installed-it)

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).